# Automating Box Authentication - Python

Tags: python, selenium, oauth, oauth-2.0, box

I'm writing an app that interacts directly with my `Box` account. I need to perform all the operations listed in the [Python SDK API](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk). Sure enough, I'm trying to get over the authentication part. Given my `client_id` and `client_secret`, I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boxsdk
import requests

def store_tokens_callback(access_token, refresh_token):
    # I don't know why this is never being called.
    print access_token, refresh_token

oauth = boxsdk.OAuth2(
    client_id="<my_client_id>",
    client_secret="<client_secret>",
    store_tokens=store_tokens_callback,
)

auth_url, csrf_token = oauth.get_authorization_url('http://127.0.0.1')
print auth_url
print csrf_token
r = requests.get(auth_url)
print r.text
client = boxsdk.Client(oauth)
```

I do get the `auth_url`:

```
https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?state=box_csrf_token_<csrf_tken>&response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1
```

However, clicking in that URL all the time won't do it. I need a way to automate this `authentication` process, so I don't have to click at this button every time:[image]

Sure enough, I could add a little `Selenium` task to get click on that button and get the url with the code, however I was looking for something easier ... between the lines.
A few questions:

- How can I automate the `auth` process in the `Box SDK`?
- Why isn't `stoke_tokens_callback` being called?

Comment: I want to understand the point of your actions, but no use so far) What are you trying to do? Box is a simple web application with a sign in (username/password) page and you're trying to pass authentication or what?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [enterprise edition documentation](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/box-platform), which allows you to interact via API calls only (no button clicking needed).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same requirement. The SDK will handle refreshing the access token when it expires, using the 60 day refresh token. The refresh token itself is also refreshed, meaning it's valid for yet another 60 days. Using the code below, having first "primed" the access and refresh tokens, will be good as long as the API is invoked at least once every 60 days. Follow the Box SDK instructions for obtaining your initial access and refresh tokens. You'll then have to install these Python modules:

```
pip.exe install keyring
pip.exe install boxsdk
```

Then use keyring.exe to prime the credential store:

```
keyring.exe set Box_Auth <AuthKey>
keyring.exe set Box_Ref <RefreshKey>
```

[From here](http://www.lifeaftersiebel.co.uk/2016/06/box-authentication-python/):

```
"""An example of Box authentication with external store"""

import keyring
from boxsdk import OAuth2
from boxsdk import Client

CLIENT_ID = 'specify your Box client_id here'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'specify your Box client_secret here'


def read_tokens():
    """Reads authorisation tokens from keyring"""
    # Use keyring to read the tokens
    auth_token = keyring.get_password('Box_Auth', 'mybox@box.com')
    refresh_token = keyring.get_password('Box_Refresh', 'mybox@box.com')
    return auth_token, refresh_token


def store_tokens(access_token, refresh_token):
    """Callback function when Box SDK refreshes tokens"""
    # Use keyring to store the tokens
    keyring.set_password('Box_Auth', 'mybox@box.com', access_token)
    keyring.set_password('Box_Refresh', 'mybox@box.com', refresh_token)


def main():
    """Authentication against Box Example"""

    # Retrieve tokens from secure store
    access_token, refresh_token = read_tokens()

    # Set up authorisation using the tokens we've retrieved
    oauth = OAuth2(
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
        access_token=access_token,
        refresh_token=refresh_token,
        store_tokens=store_tokens,
    )

    # Create the SDK client
    client = Client(oauth)
    # Get current user details and display
    current_user = client.user(user_id='me').get()
    print('Box User:', current_user.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I get the error ```The grant type is unauthorized for this client_id```
I don't understand how it solved the automation problem described in the question